# Filtering Cell Array - MatLab

Tags: matlab, filter

I got a problem that i think i have already answered, but it didnt work. Here is the deal:

I have a large cell array (about 300000x60) with some numeric data, some dates, some blank, some strings that I have to filter (like in Excel): 
For example:

```
m = ...
{   'date '    'code' 'number'  'market'  'max'     'min'    
 '01/01/2000'   'tsa'    1          0      0.9       0.0008
 '01/01/2000'   'sje'    2          0      1.8       1.5
 '01/02/2000'   'koi'    1          1      5.5       1.8
 '02/01/2000'   'sjk'    2          0      5.8       3.5
 '05/02/2000'   'kkj'    5          7      5.5       3.8 };
```

I can filter the strings ('code' column) with:

```
b = m(strcmp('tsa',m(:,2)),:);
```

and as result:

```
b =
'01/01/2000'   'tsa'    1          0      0.9       0.0008
```

(this is working perfectly).

BUT, when I tried to filter the numbers, with `c=m([m{:,3}] == 1,:);`
I had some strange answers in "c" (I got a cell array with all possible values in column 3, not only the ones which correspond to number '1')!

I want the answer like:

```
    c = m([m{:,3}] == 1,:)
    c =
    '01/01/2000'   'tsa'    1          0      0.9       0.0008
    '01/02/2000'   'koi'    1          1      5.5       1.8
```

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cell` is a reserved function in MATLAB, do not obfuscate it by creating a variable with the same name. Also, I cannot reproduce the problem with the actual snippet of code. Consider changing `cell` to `Cell` and providing code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Oleg, my bad about the name. Its actually another name!

Comment: i'm gratefull to your answer.
I know that u answered something very similar to it at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/290278
But this second part did not worked for me!
Could you help me?

Comment: Please, modify your example such that we can run into your problem.
You cannot pretend I can solve your issue by an arguable analogy with a question I answered 2years and 7 months ago!

Comment: Oleg, I'm so sorry. I changed my example, is it clearer?

Comment: I replicated your code and I am getting the answer as `c` which contains 1st and 3rd row of `m`. So what is your problem?

Comment: The `m` is not totally correctly specified. This is a matter of approach, test your code before submitting it for a question! The headers are not enclosed within single quotes (').

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer. But I still having the same problem (array 'c' contains all values of the column), i got a print screen, but dont know how to show it!
Anyone knows a different mode to filter it? another way? thanks in advance!

Comment: I just removed all my headers and this code run perfectly. Something wierd happens here when I work with headers. Thanks a lot! Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the headers in your `m` cell array.

You have to leave the headers out:

```
c = m([m{2:end,3}] == 1,:)
```

If you select the whole third column, you will get:

```
>> m{:,3}
ans =
number
ans =
     1
ans =
     2
ans =
     1
ans =
     2
ans =
     5
```

Note that the first cell in that column is of type `char` while the others are `double`.

If you concatenate them:

```
>> [m{:,3}]
ans =
number
```

Be careful here, because the numbers did NOT disappear but they were converted to `char`, in fact:

```
>> double(ans)
ans =
   110   117   109    98   101   114     1     2     1     2     5
```

What happens now, is that the comparison is carried against this enlarged array:

```
>> [m{:,3}] == 1
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

This is probably not the index you want.

To test your code, you can select a part of it and press F9. Only the highlighted code will be executed. Therefore, you don't need to type those commands in the cmd window to see what a portion of code does.

Comment: Oh. I never imagined that he was keeping headers. I removed headers and ran his code and I got perfect results

Comment: Thanks a lot! gonna test it tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer. But I still having the same problem (array 'c' contains all values of the column), i got a print screen, but dont know how to show it! Anyone knows a different mode to filter it? another way? thanks in advance

Comment: I just removed all my headers and this code run perfectly. Something wierd happens here when I work with headers. Thanks a lot! Problem solved